# Finite input impedance of voltmeters

Tags: input-impedance, voltmeter

I have a question regarding the impedance of voltmeters. I learned that a voltmeter can be modeled as follows, where \$R1\$ is the input impedance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7x5zy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I noticed that many multimeters have a \$10\,\mathrm{M}\Omega\$ input impedance on the volt range (some even more) and wondered where the (often well defined) input impedance exactly comes from. Is it coming from the ADC?

Comment: Note that 10M is a good compromise IMO. It has negligible effect on *most* circuits. The most accurate DMM in our lab had nearly infinite input impedance. This would cause the last reading to be held by stray capacitance. It would indicate a voltage without any connection often confusing the technicians.

Comment: I bet it was nowhere near infinity LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it coming from the ADC?*

The ADC never directly connects to the probe input wires directly. It will use a  buffer amplifier as intermediary and, there will also be a variable attenuator to select the different voltage ranges. The variable attenuator in conjunction with the buffer amplifier will produce the 10 MΩ input resistance seen at the probe terminals.

If it helps, here is the input selection stage of an old analogue meter (the AVO): -

[image]

<s>**Stolen**</s> acquired from [this site](http://www.richardsradios.co.uk/avosmallmeters.html)